# How to change the value of a property on toggle button IsChecked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

In my base class, I have the following:

```
    private string groupOperator;
    public string GroupOperator
    {
        get
        {
            this.groupOperator = ConvertOperatorToString();
            return this.groupOperator;
        }
        set
        {
            this.groupOperator = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupOperator");
        }
    }

    private bool isOrOperator = false;
    public bool IsOrOperator
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isOrOperator;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isOrOperator = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsOrOperator");
        }
    }

    public string ConvertOperatorToString()
    {
        if (IsOrOperator)
        {
            return "Or";
        } 

        else
        {
            return "And";
        }

    }
```

I am using a TextBlock to display the GroupOperator in my XAML. The ideal functionality is to have the string value change between And / Or based on whether or not the Toggle Button is toggled. Right now, it is not changing the TextBlock at all and I am wondering what I am doing incorrectly.

This is my XAML:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyling}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding GroupOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                            <ToggleButton x:Name="OperatorSwitch" Style="{StaticResource ToggleViewSwitch}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding IsToggleVisible, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsOrOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBaseStyling}"

                                   Text="{Binding ParentGroup.GroupOperator, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   Visibility="{Binding IsOperatorVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
```

Note: ParentGroup.GroupOperator and GroupOperator should actually be the same values when the PropertyChange is handled correctly.

Comment: Your IsOrOperator property setter should be called when the ToggleButton is toggled. Do whatever is necessary there...

Comment: What do you mean? When I toggle the button and set a breakpoint in IsOrOperator, it gets hit. It is not changing the text of the TextBlock in the View.

Comment: Sure, just update the other property there: `GroupOperator = value ? "Whatever" : "Something";`

Comment: Wow. That did it. Sorry. Thanks for the help. I am dumb, lol.

Comment: As a note, `ConvertOperatorToString()` could be written like this: `return IsOrOperator ? "Or" : "And";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should be

```
public string GroupOperator
{
    get
    {
        return ConvertOperatorToString();
    }
}

private bool isOrOperator = false;
public bool IsOrOperator
{
    get
    {
        return this.isOrOperator;
    }
    set
    {
        this.isOrOperator = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsOrOperator");
        OnPropertyChanged("GroupOperator");
    }
}
```

as setting the operator value changes more than one property you need to notify about more properties changing when it changes